# SICP - exercise 2.27 - reversing elements of a list and sublists

Tags: performance, beginner, lisp, scheme, sicp

From [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.2)

> Exercise 2.27: Modify your deep-reverse procedure of Exercise 2.18 to produce a deep-deep-reverse procedure that takes a list as argument and returns as its value the list with its elements deep-reversed and with all sublists deep-deep-reversed as well. For example,
>
> ```
> (define x (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
>
> x
> ((1 2) (3 4))
>
>
> (deep-reverse x)
> ((3 4) (1 2))
>
> (deep-deep-reverse x)
> ((4 3) (2 1))
> ```

Please review my code.

```
(define (deep-deep-reverse lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((list? lst) (append (deep-deep-reverse (cdr lst)) (list (deep-deep-reverse (car lst)))))
    (else lst)))
```

I spent an hour doing this, and I am actually extremely surprise on how small this code is in the end. How can I improve this code? Perhaps make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually indented it that way please use an editor that does
automatically - usually the individual cases of the `cond` should align,
e.g. like so:

```
(define (deep-deep-reverse lst)
  (cond
   ((null? lst) '())
   ((list? lst) (append (deep-deep-reverse (cdr lst))
                        (list (deep-deep-reverse (car lst)))))
   (else lst)))
```

The function looks good.  For clarity it might make sense to move the
middle case to the end, but it's not like that changes much.

However consider that `append` used in this way is quite expensive
because it repeatedly recreates a "long" list (from the `cdr` recursion)
to stick the "short" list (from the `car` part) at the end.

(As an exercise for the reader) you can use an accumulator instead to
avoid `append` completely (instead `cons` is enough).  The function
would look pretty similar:

```
(define (deep-deep-reverse2 lst)
  (define (aux lst acc)
    ...)
  (aux lst '()))
```

Comment: if cons sticks two lists together, it's constant time, right?

Comment: The `cons` is constant sure, the whole function definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above append gets expensive, with time and memory constraints liners to the size of the first argument. Actually recurring on each cdr of the list makes the overall function n^2 when the input is a list of lists.

The other thing to keep in mind is that list? also takes time linear time to complete. (resulting in another n^2 time constraint.) Alternatively pair? runs in constant time but doesn't protect/guard againstimproper list.  (however when you are worried about improper input you should just go ahead and check it at the beginning of a function. )

You can reverse a list by folding `cons` over it as well.

```
(define (deep-deep-reverse3 x)
    (fold (lambda (x acc) 
            (cons (if (pair? x)
                      (deep-deep-reverse3 x)
                      x)
                  acc))
          '()
           x))
```

Comment: fold is nice, but I don't think I should use it at this time since the book doesn't introduce it at this chapter.